# SQL SELECT from TABLE behaves unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, sql, select

My table has two columns, `username` and `aes_encrypt_code`. When I submit this query:

```
SELECT * FROM codes;
```

I get entries of both columns. If I send this query:

```
SELECT username, 1 FROM codes;
```

I get all the names. But if submit this query:

```
SELECT aes_encrypt_code, 1 FROM codes;
```

I get nothing, even though I know those codes are not empty.

The problem I am having is that I UNION this with SELECT of another 2 columns (while doing SQL injection) and the second row has additional encoding applied to it so it outputs some scribles. I need to get code shown in the first column.

**Why the code won't show on its own?** BTW query like:

```
SELECT aes_encrypt_code, aes_encrypt_code FROM codes;
```

outputs only the messed up codes in the second column.

**EDIT:**
The SQL command on backend looks like:

```
SELECT cA, cB AS mssg FROM messages WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]' LIMIT 1 OFFSET $_GET[offset]
```

The UNION I add as this:

```
1 UNION SELECT aes_encrypt_code, 1 FROM codes;
```

So the address line which I use for injection then looks like this:

```
...?offset=1 UNION SELECT aes_encrypt_code, 1 FROM codes;
```

Comment: Please provide your union code.

Comment: @SimonR I added the description.

Answer (score 0):

The word `code` is a mysql keyword.  Consider changing it's name in the table, if feasible, or surround it in backticks in your query.

Comment: I am very sorry, I changed the name of the actual column (dunno even why, maybe as I typed it it seemed to me redundantly long) without realising it might cause the column name to be mysql keyword. The problem is not the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

`Code` is a protected keyword in mysql. You will require backticks e.g. `

You can retrieve the column by doing

```
SELECT `code` FROM codes;
```

Comment: I am very sorry, I changed the name of the actual column (dunno even why, maybe as I typed it it seemed to me redundantly long) without realising it might cause the column name to be mysql keyword. The problem is not the keyword.